# Give JavaScript file a different extension.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure if this is possible..

I'm looking at running a HTML page and calling an external JavaScript file (like usual).

However instead of the usual /scripts.js link, I need the file to have a different extension.

For example I would like the scripts loaded in /scripts.aspx and the aspx page to have the scripts as normal.

This would be idential to the usual setup, with a different extension,

Do we know if there is any way to make this possible, to load scripts with a file that doesn't have the js extension...

I would use a js file, but the system i'm using to generate the pages outputs only aspx pages...

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried it and put the type="text/javascript" on the script tag?

Comment: Have you tried passing a different path, not *.js? I'm sure it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a different extension, but make sure you give the right headers as `application/json` or `text/javascript`.

And moreover, when you include it in the HTML, please specify the `type`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts.aspx"></script>
```

Browsers generally check for their headers for:

```
Content-type: text/javascript
```

Make sure you provide that via your server. That should be good.

Comment: There's no need to include `type` in the `script` tag, [the default is JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type).

Comment: Thank you, you're right...   I had done that but it hadn't worked... I think there was something blocking it or something as i've just tried it with a local file and an .aspx page somewhere else and it works fine!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just to be sure?

Comment: @JamesNewbert-Breen What's displaying in the Network tab? What's the content type? Show us a screenshot. Coz I am using PHP and it worked fine! I used a `.html` file as a reference to JavaScript.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Where do you stop with belt-and-braces? The default for `script` is and *always has been* JavaScript. IE briefly had a way to specify VBScript instead, but that was last century.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, I didn't understand?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sorry, "belt-and-braces" is a UK idiom (making *sure* your trousers stay up by wearing both a belt *and* braces [called suspenders in the U.S.]). E.g., you can count on this default.